# Connection drops when I connect

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

Everytime I connect to either the wireless or wired connection at the office with my laptop, the connections starts to go slower and slower until it dies. Then, if I disconnect, it eventually comes back.

This is a fresh install of Windows 7. I even thought it could be a virus or something so I formatted my hard drive. I must say that when I connect with my Ubuntu partition, everything works as expected, no slowing down, no dropping.

- The OS is Windows 7, fresh install.
- There are no other applications consuming bandwidth in my computer (downloads etc)
- All the internet connection is left as default, exactly the same as my colleages.
- I'm not the only one with windows seven, which leads me to believe it's a config problem.

Help? Please?

Comment: Are your colleagues' laptops the same as yours? it might be a simple signal power issue. If you are right next to the router does your problem still stand?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I always do is make sure I have the absolute latest drivers from the wireless card manufacturer.

Comment: I'll give that a try, but as I noted it also happens while wired up